# How to properly use Regex in ExpressJS app.use()

Tags: node.js, regex, express, server

How to use Regex inside ap.use()

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use("/files", function (req, res) {
    return res.send("I will be served instead of a files directory");
});
  
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(/a/, express.static(__dirname));

app.use(redirectUnmatched); 
function redirectUnmatched(req, res) {
    //Do something on server
    return res.send("something");;
}
let port = 80;
var server = app.listen(port);
```

If I run it in my browser (localhost), it should serve static files, when address contains letter 'a'. But instead, it fall into redirectUnmatched() function. If I change that /a/ to '/a', it works for address /a. Why it doesn't work for my regex?

Thanks!

Comment: when address contains a, what address?

Comment: Let's say http://127.0.0.1/a 
It work's only for '/a' argument in app.use(), but not for regex /a/ (which actually acording to ExpressJs docs should work...)

Comment: Have you had any luck at all with the suggestion/answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

From [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static):

> The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets. The function determines the file to serve by combining req.url with the provided root directory. When a file is not found, instead of sending a 404 response, it instead calls next() to move on to the next middleware, allowing for stacking and fall-backs.

Use case:

```
app.use(/\/[a]/gi, express.static(__dirname));
```

**note** I am not sure where the "a" should be, how many of them, if the path starts with "a" etc. The regex in the root path as above will match as many "a" in your path, irrespective of casing.

1. e.g. 127.001.123/a     -> match
2. e.g. 127.001.234/aaaa  -> match
3. e.g  127.001.101/benga -> match

Also, from the link I have attached, you can deduce that if there is an error in evaluating the path, `express.static()` with call internally next() so you may want to consider some sort of mechanism to catch the error and return the proper representation of that error to the client (404 or something).